# Como salvar em uma variavel o que é digitado no ecrã

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma página web, e por vezes os usuários pressionam alguns números.

Contudo, eu tenho um reader por usb, que eu ao ler um código ele mostra-me automaticamente 7 números, como se eu os tivesse digitado na pagina web.

Como faço para guardar estes 7 numeros que são "digitados" de forma imediata na pagina web, sem ser por input, com javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção é colocar um *listener* no documento e armazenar em um array os valores pressionados (ou keyCodes) e fazer uma busca contínua nesse array para verificar se o que ele possui é o que procuras - ou até mesmo armazenar somente o que quiser baseado no keyCode:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownPress, false);
var valoresDigitados = [];

function keyDownPress(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  valoresDigitados.push(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
}

function verValores(){
 console.log(valoresDigitados.join(""));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="verValores()">Ver valores</button>
```

Comment: É exatamente, o que eu quero, porém, aparece-me valores separados "4","2","7","6", como faço para ficarem todos juntos da forma: "4276"? Obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei um join para juntar os valores do array, @Gonçalo

Comment: Obrigado, era mesmo isto que eu procurava, já agora como faço para colocar no meu documento, pois eu coloquei e não consigo. Como faço a estrutura? Meto primeiro o <script> e o código ou só depois do html?

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta, da forma como eu coloquei o script.

Comment: Acredito que não terá problema em colocar no `head` por não manipular algum elemento que ainda não tenha sido criado.